# How to specify filter for child items in list view?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I want to open Sales Order list and specify filter via

`frappe.set_route('List', 'Sales Order', 'List', {'items': {'item_code':my_specific_item_code}})`

But it does not work this way - no filters applied to list. How could I specify a filter for child table items in `frappe.set_route` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution if someone also has a similar issue. The logic by which `frappe.set_route` object argument is transformed into filters described in `frappe/public/js/frappe/list/list_view.js` in function `ListView::parse_filters_from_route_options`. For my particular case, it should be written this way:

```
frappe.set_route('List', 'Sales Order', 'List', {'<Child Table Doctype(Sales Order Item)>.item_code':my_specific_item_code});
```